# Tokens in Play SecureSocial

Tags: playframework, securesocial

The Token Object in SecureSocial can be left in the java COde with hashmaps
or do you recommend to create a model and save it in the database?

Does it have an impact if I leave it in the hashmap?

Answer (score 0):

Model & Database are the best option, rather than the hashmap.
hashmap will not sustain a restart.